# Algorítmo "change-making" - Menor quantia de moedas possíveis

Tags: array, lógica, for

**Dado o algorítmo Change-Making:**

```
change(C1, C2, ...., Cr: valores de denominações de moedas, onde C1 > C2 > ... > Cr; n: inteiro positivo)


for i := 1 para r
     di := 0 {di conta a denominação das moedas Ci usadas}
     while n >= Ci
          di := di + 1 {adiciona uma moeda na denominação Ci}
          n := n - Ci
{di é o número de moedas na denominação Ci na troca for i = 1, 2, ...}
```

**E a pergunta:**
Considerando o algorítmo para fazer a troca e o padrão de moedas Americano($0.25, $0.10, $0.05, e $0.01).
Mostre que se introduzirmos $0.12, então o algoritmo não irá produzir uma troca usando a menor quantia de moedas possíveis.

---

Gostaria de pedir ajuda para entender a lógica ou por onde começar, pois estou perdido quanto à isso.

Desculpem pela tradução um pouco "rude" pois estou estudando isto em inglês e não sei os termos corretos em pt.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPt. Você tem uma dúvida específica sobre alguma abordagem que já tentou? Do jeito que a pergunta está, parece que você deseja que alguém faça a demonstração do que foi pedido por você (seria uma prova de faculdade?), mas esse não é o objetivo deste site.

Comment: Não é uma prova, são só exercícios de treino. Eu só não estou entendendo a lógica, e não tenho ideia por onde começar, só preciso de ajuda nisso.

Comment: Bom, edite a pergunta para colocar a sua dificuldade de forma específica. Eu diria que depurar mentalmente (o famoso ["teste de mesa"](http://www.univasf.edu.br/~marcelo.linder/arquivos_iaa/aulas/aula7.pdf)) ajuda você a entender o problema. Ignorando o fato de que o seu `n` é um inteiro (e por isso não pode receber `0.12`), você vai perceber o problema logo que chegar na primeira interação do laço (na primeira execução do `while`): a variável `n = 0.12` **não será** maior ou igual ao primeiro e maior valor de moeda `C1 = 0.25`, e por isso a execução será imediatamente interrompida.

Comment: Tudo bem, consegui criar a ideia na cabeça! Obrigado.